# multiply value from column where day+2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this:

```
date       | cpo       | production_ms | cpo_sell_profit
=======================================================
2016-08-01 | 7146      | 75187         |  
2016-08-02 | 7299      | 68925         |  
2016-08-03 | 7330      | 65534         |  
2016-08-04 | 7416      | 72133         |  
2016-08-05 | 7563      | 71442         |
```

I want to fill the **cpo_sell_profit** column but I don't know how to multiply the **production_ms** value with value from **cpo** where cpo.date = day + 2 in order to fill the **cpo_sell_profit**.

example:

75187 from 2016-08-01 multiply with 7330 from 2016-08-03

thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you tag your question with the version of SQL Server you're using. LAG / LEAD might come in handy here, but they are only available in 2012+.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: currently i'm using sql server 2014 sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,NewVal = production_ms* Lead(cpo,2,0) over (Order By date)
     From  YourTable
)
Update cte Set cpo_sell_profit = NewVal

Select * from YourTable
```

Returns

```
date        cpo     production_ms   cpo_sell_profit
2016-08-01  7146    75187           551120710
2016-08-02  7299    68925           511147800
2016-08-03  7330    65534           495633642
2016-08-04  7416    72133           0
2016-08-05  7563    71442           0
```

**Not sure what you want to do with the records out-of-scope.**  Currently set to zero, but if you put 1, you would get production_ms  .. see Lead(cpo,2,0)

Comment: can we get the value from next month when in the last day of the month sir?

Comment: @Jsnow Yes, it will be a rolling two days ahead regardless of month end

Comment: @Jsnow Gordon made a good point.  will the days be consecutive and no duplicate dates?

Comment: the days are consecutive but i dont know how to make it continue to the next month if it already reach the end of month data. sorry sir i'm still new in sql. i work in front end back in the days

Comment: @Jsnow OK, if the dates are consecutive, then you should have no worries.  8/31 will look at 9/2

Comment: now i got a problem sir, i never thought there will be duplicate date like 2016-08-01 come twice because there is unit where have different unit_id but contain same date field value

Comment: @Jsnow Easy fix.  just change the OVER clause to over (Partition By Unit_ID Order By date)

Comment: @Jsnow Thanks for the grin.

Comment: done sir john thanks. i'm still learning sql programming currently its been 3 weeks and find alot of confusions

Comment: @Jsnow I learn something new every day.  That's why I dig this site so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.cpo_sell_profit = t1.production_ms *t2.cpo
From yourtable t1 inner join yourtable t2 on t1.date = dateadd(dd,2,t2.date)
```

Comment: The `join` is safer than the lead, unless the OP can guarantee that there are no gaps in the dates.

Comment: i dont understand the gaps mean sir

Comment: OMG, @GordonLinoff commented on my answer. Hopefully upvoted too :)

Comment: @DarkKnight  Even better than an Elvis sighting.

Comment: @GordonLinoff valid point, but consider the following,  It is a Mon-Fri operation,  Thursday and Friday would be a miss if he is really looking for Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Gordan is like God father of SQL ;) So no wonder he is excited

Comment: now i got a problem sir, i never thought there will be duplicate date like 2016-08-01 come twice because there is  unit where have different unit_id but contain same date field value

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEAD` function

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Lead(cpo, 2)OVER(ORDER BY dates) AS next_val
         FROM   (VALUES ('2016-08-01',7146,75187 ),
                        ('2016-08-02',7299,68925 ),
                        ('2016-08-03',7330,65534 ),
                        ('2016-08-04',7416,72133 ),
                        ('2016-08-05',7563,71442 )) tc(dates, cpo, production_ms ))
SELECT dates,
       cpo,
       production_ms,
       production_ms * next_val
FROM   cte
```

**Result :**

```
╔════════════╦══════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║   dates    ║ cpo  ║ production_ms ║ cpo_sell_profit ║
╠════════════╬══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2016-08-01 ║ 7146 ║         75187 ║ 551120710       ║
║ 2016-08-02 ║ 7299 ║         68925 ║ 511147800       ║
║ 2016-08-03 ║ 7330 ║         65534 ║ 495633642       ║
║ 2016-08-04 ║ 7416 ║         72133 ║ NULL            ║
║ 2016-08-05 ║ 7563 ║         71442 ║ NULL            ║
╚════════════╩══════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

If you want the same value when there is no 2+dates for a `production_ms` then use `ISNULL`

```
SELECT dates,
       cpo,
       production_ms,
       production_ms * ISNULL(next_val,1)
FROM   cte
```

**Result :**

```
╔════════════╦══════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║   dates    ║ cpo  ║ production_ms ║ cpo_sell_profit ║
╠════════════╬══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2016-08-01 ║ 7146 ║         75187 ║       551120710 ║
║ 2016-08-02 ║ 7299 ║         68925 ║       511147800 ║
║ 2016-08-03 ║ 7330 ║         65534 ║       495633642 ║
║ 2016-08-04 ║ 7416 ║         72133 ║           72133 ║
║ 2016-08-05 ║ 7563 ║         71442 ║           71442 ║
╚════════════╩══════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Comment: excuse me sir what is ; with cte means sorry for noob question

Comment: @Jsnow `CTE` is a temporary result set and it can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in the same query. Check here for more info https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: In august thare are 31 days, can we make the cpo_sell_profit value from 2016-09-02 sir? or it will always be null in the end of month?

Comment: @Jsnow - Thats how it works.. It always takes the 2 record from current record ordered by dates and multiples it

Answer (score 0):

you can simply apply cross apply in this situation which doesn't required any common table expressions and temp table

```
UPDATE [cpo] set cpo_sell_profit = csp.cpo_sell_profit FROM [cpo] src
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT (src.production_ms * (SELECT production_ms FROM [cpo] WHERE date = DATEADD(day,2, src.date))) AS cpo_sell_profit
) AS csp
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table(dates date,cpo int,production_ms int,cpo_sell_profit bigint)
insert into @t values
('2016-08-01',7146,75187 ,null) 
,('2016-08-02',7299,68925,null) 
,('2016-08-03',7330,65534,null) 
,('2016-08-04',7416,72133,null) 
,('2016-08-05',7563,71442,null)
;With CTE as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by dates)rn from @t
)


select c.dates,c.cpo,c.production_ms
,c.production_ms*c1.cpo  cpo_sell_profit from cte c
left join cte c1 on c.rn+2=c1.rn

update t
set cpo_sell_profit=t.production_ms*t1.cpo
from @t t
left join @t t1 on dateadd(day,2,t.dates)=t1.dates
select * from @t
```